# Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option , while seeing the list of topics in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to kafka and zookepper, and I am trying to see the list a topic I have created, but I am getting this error: ->

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: 
        zookeeper is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:517)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:47)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

I am using this command to create the topic -

```
.\bin\kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Answer (score 0):

Kafka no longer uses Zookeeper on command flags for almost all of its tools.

Please use latest documentation at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart

```
.\bin\kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```